# HTML input date is being read back "incorrectly"

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, timezone

When I take in `3/15/2019` as the input date and then read back the time with `console.log(fromDate)` I get `Thu Mar 14 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`.

Why is it not `Fri Mar 15 2019 00:00:00` ?
Is it because of the time on my local computer?
Is there a way to achieve the desired output?

`fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fromDate").value);`

Comment: show use the code where you parse the string into the variable `fromDate`

Comment: [Javascript Date Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) - Specifically note this bit, _By default, JavaScript will use the browser's time zone and display a date as a full text string_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `new Date` consider the date as UTC, so

```
var date = new Date('3/15/2019')
```

creates the date `Fri Mar 15 2019 00:00:00`. When you print the string however it considers your actual timezone, which is `GTM-0500`, so it removes 5 hours from the original date, yielding `Thu Mar 14 2019 19:00:00`.

Comment: how am i supposed to trust that the timestamp is what it is supposed to be when it is stored on my backend if I can't read it back?

Comment: Careful.  passing a locale-specific formatted string to the `Date` constructor is implementation specific.  It *may* work, but it is not part of the ECMAScript spec.  Also, be careful that the string is generated in the same locale as it is parsed, otherwise you might mix MM/DD/YYYY with DD/MM/YYYY interpretations (1/2/2019 could be Jan 2nd or Feb 1st depending on locale).